# Perl LWP returns JSON output as string

Tags: json, perl, perl-module, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am using Perl `LWP::UserAgent` to get response from an API. Everything works good except one issue.

The API that i am using it returns response in JSON format. But I am getting it as string when i get the response through LWP module, Something like below.

```
$VAR1 = '
{"status":"success","data":[{"empid":"345232","customername":"Lee gates","dynamicid":"2342342332sd32423"},{"empid":"36.VLXP.013727..CBCL..","customername":"Lee subdirectories","dynamicid":"223f3423dsf23423423"}],"message":""}'
```

I did "`print Dumper $response`" to get the output.

One more thing, The challenge is that my client do not want to go with Perl module for JSON (use `JSON::Parse 'parse_json';`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decode the JSON string into a Perl data structure. If your version of perl is 5.14+, `JSON::PP` is included in core, so nothing to install.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);

my $json = '{"status":"success","data":[{"empid":"345232","customername":"Lee gates","dynamicid":"2342342332sd32423"},{"empid":"36.VLXP.013727..CBCL..","customername":"Lee subdirectories","dynamicid":"223f3423dsf23423423"}],"message":""}';

my $perl = decode_json $json;

print Dumper $perl;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'status' => 'success',
      'message' => '',
      'data' => [
                  {
                    'dynamicid' => '2342342332sd32423',
                    'customername' => 'Lee gates',
                    'empid' => '345232'
                  },
                  {
                    'empid' => '36.VLXP.013727..CBCL..',
                    'customername' => 'Lee subdirectories',
                    'dynamicid' => '223f3423dsf23423423'
                  }
                ]
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there other way to parse JSON string without JSON Module.? Because i do not have permission to install JSON module in the server.

Comment: You'll have to create your own parser, which is error prone, very time consuming and kind of ridiculous.

Comment: You can use `JSON::PP`, it's a core module, so it comes with perl and you don't have to install anything. It's a bit slow, but it does its job.

Comment: @redneb I didn't realize that it was part of core

Comment: @stevieb Yes, just check `corelist JSON::PP`. So if you just change your code to use `JSON::PP` it should work with no additional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Mojolicious handles this for you through when you call the `json` method on the response object:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $tx = $ua->get( 'https://www.example.com/api/endpoint' );
my $data = $tx->res->json;
```